# Lower bound on sum of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and let $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be such that $\alpha I\preceq B\preceq\beta I$ for some $\beta\geq\alpha>0$ (here, $I$ refers to the identity). I wonder whether there always exists a constant $\gamma>0$ such that the matrix inequality
\begin{equation}
  A^{\top}AB+BA^{\top}A\succeq\gamma A^{\top}A
\end{equation}
holds? Clearly, the assertion is true whenever $\alpha=\beta$.

We may also assume that $A$ has full row rank (rather than full column rank).

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what you mean by $\preceq$? Is it comparison of the spectral norm? It's possible that this is standard notation but I am not familiar with it.

Comment: @sebastian negative semidefinite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Let
$$
P=\pmatrix{5&2\\ 2&1},\ A=P^{1/2},\ B=\pmatrix{1\\ &3}.
$$
Then $A^\top AB+BA^\top A=PB+BP=\pmatrix{10&8\\ 8&6}$ is indefinite and hence it cannot be greater than or equal to the positive semidefinite matrix $\gamma A^\top A$ in positive semidefinite partial ordering.

Comment: True, but $A$ does not admit a full (row) rank.

Comment: @User129599 That doesn't matter. You can add a small $\epsilon I$ to $A$ to make it nonsingular, but $A^TAB+BA^TA$ is still indefinite.

Comment: I see, thank you very much!